# return value from a series of buttons

Tags: javascript, event-handling

so i have this code and I feel like there is a way to do this without  an if statement perhaps with "this" but i cant quite see the solution. Im trying to get the value of the button to alert when clicked on.

```
<form>
<button id="cathetersize14" type="button" value = "14g" onclick="cath()">14g</button>
<button id="cathetersize16" type="button" value = "16g" onclick="cath()">16g</button>
<button id="cathetersize18" type="button" value = "18g" onclick="cath()">18g</button>
<button id="cathetersize20" type="button" value = "20g" onclick="cath()">20g</button>
<button id="cathetersize22" type="button" value = "22g" onclick="cath()">22g</button>
<button id="cathetersize24" type="button" value = "24g" onclick="cath()">24g</button>
```

```
function cath() {


    var msg = document.getElementById("").value;
    alert(msg);



     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding a little on previous answers, maintaining separation between your HTML presentation and the JavaScript code.

```js
// Event handler for "cath" button click events
function cathHandler(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}

// Once all DOM elements have been created, attach event handlers
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    for (let button of document.getElementsByClassName("cath")) {
        button.onclick = cathHandler;
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
<button class="cath" type="button" value="14g">14g</button>
<button class="cath" type="button" value="16g">16g</button>
<button class="cath" type="button" value="18g">18g</button>
<button class="cath" type="button" value="20g">20g</button>
<button class="cath" type="button" value="22g">22g</button>
<button class="cath" type="button" value="24g">24g</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the event into the `onclick` callback and add a parameter to the `cath` function. You can then access the value as shown here:

```js
function cath($event) {
    var msg = $event.target.value;
    alert(msg);
}
```

```html
<button id="cathetersize14" type="button" value = "14g" onclick="cath(event)">14g</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You receive as parameter the event.target which the element triggering the event. This way you can do something like:

```
function cath(event) {
  alert(event.target.value);
}
```

Hopefully this is the problem you wanted to solve!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can eliminate the repetitive `onclick` in your html by selecting the button elements in your javascript. You could select by tag but I added class names to your elements for the example below (assuming you may have other button elements on the page).

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('cathetersize');
for (const button of buttons) {
  button.onclick = (event) => {
    alert(event.target.value);
  };
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button class="cathetersize" id="cathetersize14" type="button" value="14g">14g</button>
  <button class="cathetersize" id="cathetersize16" type="button" value="16g">16g</button>
  <button class="cathetersize" id="cathetersize18" type="button" value="18g">18g</button>
  <button class="cathetersize" id="cathetersize20" type="button" value="20g">20g</button>
  <button class="cathetersize" id="cathetersize22" type="button" value="22g">22g</button>
  <button class="cathetersize" id="cathetersize24" type="button" value="24g">24g</button>
</form>
```

Comment: See answer from @Tibrogargan above for the cleanest approach.